# How to have a discussion in Trello similar to the ones in Teambox

Tags: trello

One cool thing about Teambox is that you have a dedicated discussion page. What’s the best way to have a discussion in Trello?

Answer (score 1):

I'd say integrating Trello with a service like [HipChat](http://hipchat.com/) through a service such as [Zapier](https://zapier.com) is your best bet for now.

HipChat is free for small teams (5 members).

Zapier has a limited number of integrations (5) and tasks for the free plan.